# Как вызвать NullPointerException в Java, не используя throw?

Tags: java, исключения

Нужен наиболее простой способ вызвать `NullPointerException`

Comment: ((Object) null).toString();

Comment: `System.load(null);`

Comment: вы явно пошли не по тому пути. вы хотите выбросить исключение без использования механизмов пробрасывания исключений. это как рвать гланды без использования носоглотки. посему советую подробнее описать, что именно вы делаете, а то так и в трех соснах заблудиться недолго...